# CloudWatch Alarm created via Cloudformation Value of property OKActions must be of type List of String

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

my alarm set in cloudformation:

```
ClientErrorAlarm:
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
Properties:
  ......
  OKActions:
    - !Ref SNSSquadCast
  ......
```

returns error: `Value of property OKActions must be of type List of String`

so does

```
OKActions:
    - Ref: SNSSquadCast
```

I'm not sure what else to try

Comment: What is `SNSSquadCast`?

Comment: its just what I named the sns resource in cloudformation template.

Answer (score 0):

so, I don't have a specific reason for why this was happening. I just deleted the stacks and redeployed and it worked